# Cannot load font in JRE 8

Tags: java, fonts, awt, java-8

I cannot load a font from an S3 Inputstream in JRE 8. I do not have issue if a system is installed with JRE 7, JDK 7, or even JDK 8.

```
val fontInputStream = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, objectKey).getObjectContent

val customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontInputStream).deriveFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 20F)
```

The error that I got is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
        at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:31)
        at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:11)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at Main$.main(Main.scala:11)
        at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

I tried to load the inputstream to a temp file, but it does not help. I also tried to load a font directly from a local file, but I got a different error with getting font metadata. Here is the error log.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:219)
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:776)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at java.awt.Font.<init>(Font.java:614)
        at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1056)
        at Main$.delayedEndpoint$Main$1(Main.scala:32)
        at Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:11)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at Main$.main(Main.scala:11)
        at Main.main(Main.scala)
```

So, this is not a problem with inputstream, but rather with the loading of the font itself in JRE 8.

This seems like a bug in JRE 8 Font.

I am loading a font to use to draw a string in a picture.
My code is run in a Docker container using images java:7-jre (ok), java:7-jdk (ok), java:8-jre (fail), java:8-jdk (ok).

Comment: and what's the URL for the font? You may want to run it through TTX, and see if that throws any errors, as well as try loading it in Font Forge, which is even more finicky when it comes to telling you the font you're loading has bad values somewhere.

Comment: The openjdk blog explains this problem here: https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/01/prerequisites-for-font-support-in-adoptopenjdk/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that this is a problem with the `openjdk-8-jre-headless` installation. This is the installation in the Docker image for java 8 JRE. I simply install `openjdk-8-jre` (without headless) and the problem goes away.

If you look at the error log, the loading of the font require awt X11, which is missing from `headless` version of JRE.

Comment: To further clarify the answer, the `headless` flavor of JRE does not support font loading because a headless environment is one without UI, thus no need for font. The non `headless` version, however, supports UI, thus supports font.

Answer (score 24):

I get the same error with openjdk:8-jre-alpine. Switching to openjdk:8-jre helps.

```
--- FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
+++ FROM openjdk:8-jre
```

Comment: Switching from Alpine to jre solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 17):

We also got that error when using tomcat:8.0.38-jre8-alpine. That image is missing the fontconfig.
Instead of switching to a different image you could also install the `ttf-dejavu` package.

```
apk add --update ttf-dejavu
```

Answer (score 13):

For alpine and openjdk : 
Use `RUN apk --update add fontconfig ttf-dejavu`
Worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

On CentOS headless JRE is missing the `fontconfig` dependency:

```
yum install fontconfig
```

Also one might need to install at least one font (`dejavu`, `liberation`, etc).

Answer (score 6):

For me this resolved issue:

```
apt-get install -y libfontconfig1
```

Comment: For Docker add these line to remove this issue : RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libfontconfig1

Answer (score 1):

I spent days suffering with it until I saw this github thread and made the night happy. it's practically calling GraphicsEnvironment again

[link here](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/124#issuecomment-675629775)

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are no longer part of JDK 11, fonts installed on host should be used now. so, you need to install and keep fontconfig in classpath.

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452775/2787184

Answer (score 0):

We faced this problem when we **moved from oracle jdk8 to openjdk 1.8.0_392** on centOS 6
We had to install :

```
sudo yum -y install fontconfig freetype dejavu-sans-fonts
```

Then you can check your fonts using :

```
fc-list
```