# Where are fonts defined/installed for Openjdk Java on linux

Tags: fonts, java

Installed Oracle 8 jdk on Ubuntu, within jre/lib it has various fontProperties files plus a fonts dir containing fonts. But when installed OpenJdk 8 there is no such fonts folder on font files within jre/lib.

So where does it get its fonts from, does it come with any fonts on depen on the system having some fonts installed somewhere else.

Update
Based on advise from gerynix

`fc-list`

returns no fonts

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames()
```

gives

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:219)
        at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:774)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
        at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
        at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getFontManagerForSGE(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:190)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:224)
        at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:252)
        at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:94)
        at Fonts.main(Fonts.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets it from the environment on top of which you are running your application.

Look into:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames()
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html

Comment: so I assume if you  have a stripped down linux machine with no fonts then any code that depended on some font being installed would fail, is there a linux command I can use to check what fonts are installed ?

Comment: fc-list, first google search result for "linux check available fonts"

Comment: okay, Ive done both commands clearly have no fonts. So the machien is a piece of hardware running linux i cannot just update it like a usual machine, is there a way I can just install a font for use by my Java application by copying a file over without affecting anything else.

Comment: what flavour of linux are you using?

Comment: Im not really sure but its arm32 hardware, uname -a gives Linux N1 3.3.4-ROMROOT-NT1 #1 Thu Feb 2 10:21:27 JST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: cat /etc/*release to reveal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139611/discussion-between-gerynix-and-paul-taylor).

Comment: Thanks in the end i found creating a dir called fonts within the jre lib folder and copying some fonts from your suggestion of https://github.com/google/fonts/archive/master.zip worked, I didnt need to run fc-cache -f