# FastQC fails to process fastq sequence file - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, bioinformatics

I am trying to run fastqc on RNA seq (.fastq) and I get this issue that I haven't managed to fix yet:

```
Approx 5% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 10% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 15% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 20% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 25% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 30% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 35% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 40% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 45% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 50% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 55% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 60% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 65% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 70% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 75% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 80% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 85% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 90% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Approx 95% complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Analysis complete for SRR5280293.fastq
Failed to process file SRR5280293.fastq
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:219)
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:774)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
    at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance(SunFontManager.java:250)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:264)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(SunGraphics2D.java:855)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Graphs.QualityBoxPlot.paint(QualityBoxPlot.java:88)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.print(JComponent.java:1202)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.AbstractQCModule.writeDefaultImage(AbstractQCModule.java:68)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Modules.PerBaseQualityScores.makeReport(PerBaseQualityScores.java:199)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Report.HTMLReportArchive.<init>(HTMLReportArchive.java:131)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.OfflineRunner.analysisComplete(OfflineRunner.java:155)
    at uk.ac.babraham.FastQC.Analysis.AnalysisRunner.run(AnalysisRunner.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In the end, I get a fastqc.zip file which is empty. No html report... 
I run it on CentOS 7.3 and my java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b14, mixed mode)
```

Can someone help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your java installation. Take a look at the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626136/cannot-load-font-in-jre-8) and hopefully, the issue should get resolved.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem here, the only successful way were to remove my apt version (because as mattbull says [here](https://discourse.climb.ac.uk/t/problem-running-fastqc/553), "FastQC from aptitude has been broken for ages") with:

```
sudo apt-get purge fastqc
```

And then logout and login to your instance to reset the PATH.

Then, search the 0.11.8 FastQC version in Anaconda because we know that the good working jdk version is put in the package.

```
conda search -c bioconda fastqc
```

Then, install it with

```
conda install -c bioconda fastqc=0.11.8
```

And at least the bug disappear for me only with this and I can use normally FastQC.