# Java 11 does not have fonts?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, fonts, apache-poi

I'm using Java 11 Corretto + Spring Boot with Apache POI but I'm facing issues when using on AWS Lambda. Works fine if I run as "normal" API but fails when running servless in a AWS lambda.

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(1000)) {
    SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("test"); //error here!!
    } ...
```

> Caused by: java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error: No physical fonts
> found.    at
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.lambda$getDefaultPhysicalFont$0(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
> at
> java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.doDeferredInitialisation(Unknown
> Source)   at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.getSlotFont(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.initMapper(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeGlyphMapper.(Unknown Source)
> at java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.getMapper(Unknown Source)    at
> java.desktop/sun.font.CompositeFont.canDisplay(Unknown Source)    at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Unknown Source)     at
> java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(Unknown Source)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.(Unknown Source)  at
> org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:285)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.AutoSizeColumnTracker.(AutoSizeColumnTracker.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.(SXSSFSheet.java:84)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:705)
> at
> org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:724)

I tried to create a fix to the fonts but I have no idea how to proceed

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadFonts() {
    URL configURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fontconfig.properties");
    String path = configURL != null ? configURL.getPath() : null;
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    LOGGER.info("Loading font config file: {}", path);
    props.put("sun.awt.fontconfig", path);

    String[] fonts;
    try {
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        LOGGER.warn("Reloading Fonts");
    }
    try {
        fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

        for (String font : fonts) {
            LOGGER.info("Available Font: {}", font);
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not load Fonts");
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
version=1
sequence.allfonts=default
```

When running on AWS Lambda it outputs some fonts to the logs so I don't understand why I get that error:

> ```
> 2022-05-31 16:00:14  INFO  Starting Lambda Container Handler
> 2022-05-31 16:00:18  INFO  Loading font config file: /var/task/fontconfig.properties
> 2022-05-31 16:00:18  INFO  Available Font: Dialog
> 2022-05-31 16:00:18  INFO  Available Font: DialogInput
> 2022-05-31 16:00:18  INFO  Available Font: Monospaced
> 2022-05-31 16:00:18  INFO  Available Font: SansSerif
> 2022-05-31 16:00:18  INFO  Available Font: Serif
> ```

Any idea how to add physical fonts and why can't the POI use the available fonts that output to the logs?

**EDIT:**
I also tried to run as headless but I get the same error:

```
`props.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");`
```

Comment: `when using on AWS Lambda.`  This is running on a server?  Most servers are "headless," that is they have no GUI at all.  I'm guessing that might mean no fonts too.  You might need to Google for how to install Java font packages on a unix device.

Comment: I just clicked through a tutorial for AWS Lambda.  That is definitely a server, they just market it as "serverless."  (Never read the marketing drivel.)  If you can't install packages then I don't think you can use it for this function. Get a real server.

Comment: There is always a server. "Serverless" just means you don't have to manage the server. If you can't fix this by bundling the fonts in your Lambda deployment package, then you may need to look into deploying your Lambda function as a Docker container instead, where you will have more control of the runtime environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Fonts bundling

> Any idea how to add physical fonts

The *Oracle JDK* product from Oracle [stopped bundling fonts](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8191522) as of Java 11.

The [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project does not bundle fonts, at least not in recent versions.

The *Corretto* JDK from Amazon product is based on OpenJDK codebase. Given your report, apparently they do not bundle fonts.

You must choose to:

- Rely on the fonts provided by the host OS.
- Bundle fonts within your Java app. Be careful to study license terms. Some fonts allow such bundling, some don’t. Some require a fee, some don’t. Some require an acknowledgment, some don’t.
- Obtain a JDK from a vendor that includes fonts.

I know of at least one such vendor: Azul Systems bundles fonts with their *Azul Platform Core* commercial product.

There may be other such vendors that I’m not aware of. Many vendors provide JDK binaries and installers. These vendors include Adoptium, SAP, BellSoft, Microsoft, Azul Systems, Amazon, Oracle, Red Hat/IBM, Pivotal, and more.

## Physical fonts versus logical fonts

> why can't the POI use the available fonts that output to the logs

The fonts you listed in your logs are *logical* fonts, not *physical* fonts. The distinction is clearly documented in the Javadoc for the [`Font`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html) class.

To use a logical font name, you must have some backing physical font. If no fonts exist within your app, within your JDK, or within your host OS, then the logical fonts cannot work.

## Fonts for AWS Lambda

Regarding making fonts available in AWS Lambda, perhaps these two pages might help. (Thanks to [jarmod for the links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462871/amazon-corretto-11-openjdk-does-not-have-any-fonts#comment128012006_72462871).)

- [*Configuring fonts for AWS Lambda*](https://forum.aspose.com/t/configuring-fonts-for-aws-lambda/234036/5)
- [*AWS Lambda Fonts & libfontconfig*](https://medium.com/creditorwatch/aws-lambda-fonts-libfontconfig-5e837281a4ce) by [Alberto Cubeddu](https://medium.com/@acubeddu87)

The basic idea is to create a `/fonts` folder within your package. Incude a `fonts.conf` file within, with XML configuration elements. Place your bundled fonts files alongside that config file.

## License terms

Be aware that **some fonts are commercial**, with a license that requires a fee. When bundling/deploying fonts, be sure to verify that you are meeting the terms of their license.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but any ideia how I can put physical fonts in my java lambda?